# TraceCallBackEvent usage for detecting idle SQL connections

Tags: delphi, connection, trace, dbx

Using Delphi 2006; My aim is to check wether a TSQLConnection instance is idle or not. Therefore, i am setting a Datetime "m_dLastActivity" to "now" each time activity is seen.

As TSQLMonitor is buggy in its trace handling and causes memory problems (see http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=89216), i try to register a trace callback of my own using SetTraceCallbackEvent:

```
procedure TConnectionGuard.SetSQLConnection(const Value: TSQLConnection);
begin
   ...    
   if Assigned ( Value )
   and not ( csDesigning in ComponentState ) then begin
      ...
      m_SQLConnection.SetTraceCallbackEvent(U_ConnectionGuard.OnTraceCallBack, integer(self));
      ...
   end;
end;
```

The callback is just returning the data to the TConnectionGuard object that registered it:

```
function OnTraceCallBack( CallType: TRACECat; CBInfo: Pointer): CBRType; stdcall;
var Desc: pSQLTraceDesc;
begin
   Desc := pSQLTraceDesc(CBInfo);
   Result := TConnectionGuard(Desc.ClientData).OnTraceCallBack(CallType, CBInfo);
end;
```

The event itself:

```
function TConnectionGuard.OnTraceCallBack(CallType: TRACECat; Desc: pSQLTraceDesc): CBRType;
begin
   m_dLastActivity := now;
   Result := cbrUSEDEF;
end;
```

So far, so good, it works. But i am quite uncomfortable with the fact that i have no idea what i have to pass back as CBRType result (defined in DBCommonTypes.pas) to have a minimum performance impact. In fact, i have no idea what i am answering, as the given parameter CallCAT provides no hint how to read / handle it.

Does anyone know if cbrUSEDEF is the right thing to have tracing at a minimum?

**EDIT**: I realized through the source code of TSQLMonitor that the CBInfo pointer given is not the client info i registered, but a psQLTraceDesc that contains the client info (in this case, the pointer to my Guard). I have adapted the methods to that fact...

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).